# HP 1910-48G internal network can't ping other ip pools

Tags: networking, ip, hp, vlan

I am struggling with setting up my hp procurve v1910-48G.

I created 5 vlans:

```
VLAN ID 1 192.168.0.1/24 <- default
VLAN ID 10 192.168.1.254/24
VLAN ID 20 192.168.2.254/24
VLAN ID 30 192.168.3.254/24
VLAN ID 40 192.168.4.254/24
VLAN ID 50 192.168.5.254/24
```

and what i want is that vlans 10,20,30,40,50 can speak with each-other so i link vlan ports

VLAN Port Detail

```
GE1/0/44 1 10,20,30,40,50 Hybrid 1
GE1/0/45 1 10,20,30,40,50 Hybrid 1
GE1/0/46 1 10,20,30,40,50 Hybrid 1
GE1/0/47 1 10,20,30,40,50 Hybrid 1 
GE1/0/48 1 10,20,30,40,50 Hybrid 1
```

And setup IPv4 routing:

```
Active route table

Destination IP Address            Mask Protocol Preference      Next Hop      Interface
               0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0   Static            192.168.0.254 Vlan-interface1
             127.0.0.0       255.0.0.0   Direct          0     127.0.0.1    InLoopBack0
             127.0.0.1 255.255.255.255   Direct          0     127.0.0.1    InLoopBack0
           192.168.0.0   255.255.255.0   Direct          0   192.168.0.1 Vlan-interface1
           192.168.0.1 255.255.255.255   Direct          0     127.0.0.1 InLoopBack0
           192.168.1.0   255.255.255.0   Direct          0 192.168.1.254 Vlan-interface10
         192.168.1.254 255.255.255.255   Direct          0     127.0.0.1 InLoopBack0
           192.168.2.0   255.255.255.0   Direct          0 192.168.2.254 Vlan-interface20
         192.168.2.254 255.255.255.255   Direct          0     127.0.0.1 InLoopBack0
           192.168.3.0   255.255.255.0   Direct          0 192.168.3.254 Vlan-interface30
         192.168.3.254 255.255.255.255   Direct          0     127.0.0.1 InLoopBack0<br>
           192.168.4.0   255.255.255.0   Direct          0 192.168.4.254 Vlan-interface40
         192.168.4.254 255.255.255.255   Direct          0     127.0.0.1 InLoopBack0
           192.168.5.0   255.255.255.0   Direct          0 192.168.5.254 Vlan-interface50
         192.168.5.254 255.255.255.255   Direct          0     127.0.0.1 InLoopBack0
```

On port 44 / 45 / 46 / 47 / 48 at the HP 1910-48G i attached a unmanaged switch on each port.

And on the unmanaged switch i connect a pc. For my test i connected two windows 7 pc's each to another switch and try to ping each-other, example:

Windows 7 pc1 ip `192.168.1.10`

Windows 7 pc2 ip `192.168.2.10`

none of he two pc's are able to ping the other network.

I hope i explaining it well and someone can help me out what going wrong with my setup.

Thanks a lot for your feedback.

Comment: What is the routing table in Windows 7 PCs? What is the ping message?